# JavaScript, how to continue expression on the next line

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

Is there a way to continue expression on the next line in JS?

```
const result = 'one' ? 1 :
  'two' ? 2 :
          3
```

turn it into

```
const result = \
  'one' ? 1 :
  'two' ? 2 :
          3
```

and turn this

```
return condition1 && 
  condition2 && 
  condition3
```

into

```
return \
  condition1 && 
  condition2 && 
  condition3
```

So it would looks better?

It's possible to do it like that but I hope there are better way

```
return true &&
  condition1 && 
  condition2 && 
  condition3
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first desired snippet

```
const result =
  'one' ? 1 :
  'two' ? 2 :
          3
```

is already allowed, but due to [automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion), the `return` statement must be written as:

```
return (
  condition1 && 
  condition2 && 
  condition3
)
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes - just use parentheses for the `return` one:

```
return (
  condition1 &&
  condition2 &&
  condition3
);
```

If you leave a newline after the `return` keyword, it'll return `undefined`.

Your ternary operator can be used as-is, but consider also using parentheses to decrease confusion:

```
const result = 
  "one" ? 1 : (
  "two" ? 2 : 3
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very much about personal preference, here's how I like to write those:

```js
const result = 
  "one"
  ? 1
  : ("two"
    ? 2
    : 3);

return (
  condition1
  && condition2
  && condition3
);
```